# Questions on Ubuntu 13.04 on ASUS Z87-PRO motherboard : Bluetooth and Display

Tags: 13.04, bluetooth, hdmi

I have recently purchased a *ASUS Z87-PRO motherboard* and installed Ubuntu 13.04. Everything seemed working fine. But, I have the following questions.

1) Ubuntu detected the bluetooth. When I tried to search my phone, it couldn't find it. But if I switched to Windows 7, the bluetooth worked perfectly (after installed all ASUS come-with drivers).

Is it a driver problem ?

If it's, is there a new linux bluetooth driver out there?

2) I connected my system to the monitor using HDMI, it worked fine. But I was wondering why `xrandr -q` showed:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.9  
   1280x720       50.0     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        60.0
```

Since the MB supports *DisplayPort 1.2 monitor daisy chain up to 3 displays*, I am not surprise to see *DP1*, *DP2* and *DP3* there. How come it also showed *HDMI1*, *HDMI2* and *HDMI3* ?

But it only has one *HDMI* port. how can this happen ?

Comment: did you ever sort out Bluetooth in Ubuntu?

Comment: I have just started working with the Asus Z87-Pro. Apart from the problem you have described which is also happening here there is another ACPI general problem that might be the cause of several other symptoms: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi/+bug/1271978

Please check if you are also experiencing this and the rest of the issues you have mentioned.