# ASUS Z87 Pro Bluetooth not finding other devices with 13.10

Tags: 13.10, bluetooth, asus, atheros

Ubuntu 13.10 installed on a machine with ASUS Z87 Pro motherboard, which ships with it's "Wi-Fi GO!" wireless networking built in, which is based on a Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (includes WiFi + Bluetooth 4 capabilities).

I can turn on Bluetooth, scan for devices, but it never finds anything. I have another machine running Windows sitting next to it, and that sees the devices I am making visible.

I installed Windows on my machine and once the drivers were loaded, I was able to use Bluetooth without any issues, so the hardware is functioning correctly.

I admit I am a little confused about how the Atheros AR9462 works, since the WiFi seems to be on the PCI bus, while the Bluetooth is on USB - at least, that's what I've gathered.

Information:

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

.

```
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    24:0A:64:1A:D1:C8
```

.

```
$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    3.997672] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    3.997689] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.997694] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.997696] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.997702] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.517156] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.517158] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.517163] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.520730] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    4.520737] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    4.520738] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

.

```
$ hciconfig
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 24:0A:64:1A:D1:C8  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:691 acl:0 sco:0 events:52 errors:0
    TX bytes:2198 acl:0 sco:0 commands:50 errors:0
```

.

```
$ sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0b05:17d0 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 17ef:6009 Lenovo ThinkPad Keyboard with TrackPoint
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04a9:160a Canon, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
```

.

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-gnome 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:17:04 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is the lspci section about the Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter, but I don't see any reference to Bluetooth anywhere.

```
$ sudo lspci -vnn
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:850e]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at efd00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
Expansion ROM at efd80000 [disabled] [size=64K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable+ 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Here is the complete output of lspci, for reference:

```
$ sudo lspci -vnn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller     [8086:0c00] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>

00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller [8086:0c01] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [140] Root Complex Link
    Capabilities: [d94] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0412] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at ef800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
    Memory at efe34000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8086:8c31] (rev 05) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at efe20000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:8c3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at efe3f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V [8086:153b] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:859f]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at efe00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at efe3d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=32]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 [8086:8c2d] (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at efe3c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:855f]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
    Memory at efe30000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:8c10] (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 [8086:8c12] (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: efd00000-efdfffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:8c1a] (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: efc00000-efcfffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 [8086:8c26] (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at efe3b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Z87 Express LPC Controller [8086:8c44] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:8c02] (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    I/O ports at f0d0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0c0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at efe3a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:8c22] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 6
    Memory at efe39000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:850e]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at efd00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at efd80000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

04:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller [1b21:0612] (rev 01) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:858d]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    I/O ports at e050 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e040 [size=4]
    I/O ports at e030 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e020 [size=4]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=32]
    Memory at efc00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512]
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, I think the kernel is missing a driver or the driver does not recognise the USB ID. I've the same problem in Debian Jessie and filed a bug report for Debian[1] already. You may want to do the same for Ubuntu. [1] http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=733507

Comment: I also read this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/378465/questions-on-ubuntu-13-04-on-asus-z87-pro-motherboard-bluetooth-and-display and posted a bug that might be making the Bluetooth issue (Complementing on Masida) in this launchpad bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi/+bug/1271978

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth issue is not yet solved in 14.04 since it is more of a supported driver issues than a bug. I went to even think about compiling latest Bluez version because I thought it was not drivers. But after testing Kernel 3.14 and 3.15 I found out that the Bluetooth was working. My smartphone detected the Asus Bluetooth and vice versa.

So starting with the Kernel 3.14.x bluetooth support will be available for the Asus Z87-Pro

If you do wish to try it out (Be warned, this could create other problems. None for me at the moment but if I do get one I'll jump to 3.13): You need to go to http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and search for the 3.14 kernel or even 3.15. Since I have the 14.04 64-bit version I used the following:

- [Kernel 3.14.1](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/)

  - [Linux Header 64 Bit](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/linux-headers-3.14.1-031401-generic_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_amd64.deb)
  - [Linux Header Generic](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/linux-headers-3.14.1-031401_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_all.deb)
  - [Linux Image](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/linux-image-3.14.1-031401-generic_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_amd64.deb)
- [Kernel 3.15 RC2](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.15-rc2-trusty/)

  - [Linux Header 64 Bit](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.15-rc2-trusty/linux-headers-3.15.0-031500rc2-generic_3.15.0-031500rc2.201404201435_amd64.deb)
  - [Linux Header Generic](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.15-rc2-trusty/linux-headers-3.15.0-031500rc2_3.15.0-031500rc2.201404201435_all.deb)
  - [Linux Image](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.15-rc2-trusty/linux-image-3.15.0-031500rc2-generic_3.15.0-031500rc2.201404201435_amd64.deb)

For more information regarding the Network changes since 3.14 you can look in: [Kernel Newbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.14-DriversArch#head-055456fcd25cf08bd9f925565a8f60cc740ecdf7)

After you have downloaded the DEB packages you need (Look in the respective folder for the actual ones you need). Then put them all inside the same folder and run the following command inside that folder:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

This will install each DEB package found in that folder. The following image shows Ubuntu 14.04 working correctly with the Bluetooth (Using any kernel from 3.14 and above). Ubuntu 14.10 simply works out of the box:

[image]

The image is using a Samsung headphone (HM1200). Works correctly with Hangouts, Skype, VLC and listening to music.

Comment: Thanks - I've read that 3.14 (or even 3.15) may be available in 14.04.1 in July, so if this is the case, I might wait until then to do a full upgrade.

Comment: I'm running 14.04.1 right now.  I had to configure the btusb module to load at startup using $ echo "btusb" | sudo tee --append /etc/modules.  However, my PC can't see other BT devices, and other BT devices can't see my PC, even when in pairing mode.  Ubuntu just shows "Searching for devices..."

Comment: @PJSingh Using a newer kernel or waiting for 14.10 will solve it. Right Now I am using 14.04 with kernel 3.17 and 14.10. give me a moment to paste an image for the BT working.

Comment: @Luis Alvarado, thank you for the update.  Utopic Unicorn will ship with kernel 3.16. Will BT work with this kernel, or do we need to install 3.17 like you did?

Comment: @PJSingh I personally tested 3.14, 3.15, 3.16 and 3.17. It works starting with 3.14 and even though it does not appear in http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.14-DriversArch it works correctly. Tested with the Samsung HD1200, Samsung S4 and Samsung S4 Mini. Also just noticed right now I tested everything with Samsung.