# Can't activate Bluetooth on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, acer

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Acer Aspire 4830TG. I can't activate Bluetooth. I have no Icon in the top bar (the check box in the settings does nothing) and when I click activate in the settings nothing happens. Any idea how I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a newer kernel, as suggested in this answer to a similar question: [ASUS Z87 Pro Bluetooth not finding other devices with 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/a/458448/100356)

Here are instructions to upgrade your kernel: [How can I install 3.16 kernel on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506956/how-can-i-install-3-16-kernel-on-ubuntu-14-04)

**General Instructions To Install A New Kernel**

The latest kernel available for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty is 3.14.1.  The files can be downloaded at: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/

The latest kernel available for Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic is 3.17.1.  The files can be downloaded at: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.1-utopic/

Other kernel versions can be downloaded from: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

You would need to download three files:

1. linux-headers-*-generic_[i386|amd64].deb
2. linux-headers-*_all.deb
3. linux-image-*-generic_[i386|amd64].deb

Note: Replace "[i386|amd64]" with "amd64" if you need the 64 bit kernel, or with "i386" if you need the 32 bit kernel.

After downloading, you can double click on the *.deb files to install them.  However, you can also use the simple command line steps below.

**Specific Instructions To Install A New Kernel (3.14.1 or 3.17.1)**

Note: I've included instructions for kernel 3.14.1, but for me, bluetooth did not work with this kernel.  Bluetooth did work with kernel 3.17.1, available for Utopic.  Which kernel works really depends on whether or not the kernel you  install has support for your bluetooth hardware adapter.  There is an issue with the bcmwl wireless drivers in kernel 3.17.1, and I've included a fix for that as well.

```
cd ~/Downloads
mkdir kernel
cd kernel
```

Only execute the next three lines to download the *64 bit kernel version 3.17.1*.

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.1-utopic/linux-headers-3.17.1-031701-generic_3.17.1-031701.201410150735_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.1-utopic/linux-headers-3.17.1-031701_3.17.1-031701.201410150735_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.1-utopic/linux-image-3.17.1-031701-generic_3.17.1-031701.201410150735_amd64.deb
```

Only execute the next three lines to download the *32 bit kernel version 3.17.1*.

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.1-utopic/linux-headers-3.17.1-031701-generic_3.17.1-031701.201410150735_i386.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.1-utopic/linux-headers-3.17.1-031701_3.17.1-031701.201410150735_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.1-utopic/linux-image-3.17.1-031701-generic_3.17.1-031701.201410150735_i386.deb
```

Only execute the next three lines to download the *64 bit kernel version 3.14.1*.

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/linux-headers-3.14.1-031401-generic_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/linux-headers-3.14.1-031401_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/linux-image-3.14.1-031401-generic_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_amd64.deb
```

Only execute the next three lines to download the *32 bit kernel version 3.14.1*.

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/linux-headers-3.14.1-031401-generic_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_i386.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/linux-headers-3.14.1-031401_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/linux-image-3.14.1-031401-generic_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_i386.deb
```

List downloaded files *.deb files.

```
ls -la
```

List installed kernels, before installation of new kernel.

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Install new downloaded kernel.

```
sudo dpkg --install *.deb
```

List installed kernels, including new kernels.

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Reboot your computer so it loads the new kernel.

Verify that you are now using the newly installed kernel.

```
uname -r
```

**Optional Fix For "bcmwl kernel module failed to build" Error in Kernel 3.17.1**

If you install kernel 3.17.1 and are using using the bcmwl wireless driver, you may get a "bcmwl kernel module failed to build" error.
See [Launchpad Bug # 1358966](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1358966) for more information.

Only execute the next line to fix bug 1358966 for kernel version *3.17.1, 64 bit*.

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu2/+build/6555554/+files/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248%2Bbdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Only execute the next line to fix bug 1358966 for kernel version *3.17.1, 32 bit*.

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu2/+build/6555555/+files/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248%2Bbdcom-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

Remove the old bcmwl driver.

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Install the new bcmwl driver.

```
sudo dpkg --install bcmwl-kernel-source_*.deb
```

Reboot.

Note, you might have to delete your existing wireless connections and recreate them.

**Uninstall New Kernel**

Here are instructions to remove the new kernel, if you need to.

List installed kernels, before removal of new kernel.

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Only execute the next line to remove *kernel version 3.14.1*.

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.14.1* linux-headers-3.14.1*
```

Only execute the next line to remove *kernel version 3.17.1*.

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.14.1* linux-headers-3.17.1*
```

Update initramfs ("Initial Ram File System").

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

List installed kernels, after removal of the new kernel.

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

**Get A New Kernel As An Official Upgrade**

If you are willing to wait, note that a newer kernel will be released in February 2015 for Trusty 14.04.2, as per this answer:

[When will kernel 3.14 be available in the repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/a/549171/100356)

Comment: How do I upgrade the kernel in detail? I have never done that.

Comment: I edited the response to add instructions on installing a kernel.  If you have Nvidia graphics, the Plymouth splash screen may stop displaying; there are posts on AskUbuntu on how to remedy that side effect.

Comment: thanks I will try it out tomorrow and then reply if it worked or not.

Comment: Good luck.  Ultimately, it will depend on whether or not they have included drivers for your Bluetooth adapter in the updated kernel.  But, you can always revert back as I have described.

Comment: I updated the instructions to include steps to install kernel 3.17.1, since I found that kernel 3.14.1 did not fix Bluetooth for me.  (Kernel 3.14.1 might work for you, so it may be worth trying).